# Large file upload using ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

looking for a large file upload solution on MVC3. There's a few examples in ASP.Net web forms but not found what I'm looking for in MVC.

The files will be about 400mb in size, so will need to be streamed.

Thanks - Pete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [SlickUpload](http://krystalware.com/blog/archive/2011/05/06/SlickUpload-6-RC.aspx), it's very solid and the upcoming release will have MVC 1/2/3 support.